# JavaScript function that uses switch statement on the type of value

Tags: javascript

I've been working with the JavaScript learning modules found in **[CodeAcademy.com](http://www.codeacademy.com)** and find myself unredeemed in chapter 4, module 8 (switch - control flow statements)

Please see below for example request:

```
// Write a function that uses switch statements on the
// type of value. If it is a string, return 'str'. 
// If it is a number, return 'num'. 
// If it is an object, return 'obj'
// If it is anything else, return 'other'.
// compare with the value in each case using ===
```

and this is what I was able to code:

```
function StringTypeOf(value) {
var value = true
switch (true) {
 case string === 'string': 
   return "str"; 
   break;
 case number === 'number':
   return "num"; 
   break;
 case object === 'object':
   return "obj"; 
   break;
 default: return "other";
 }
  return value;
}
```

Can someone please hint or tell me what is missing here?

Comment: `switch( typeof value ) {case "string": ... case "number": ... }`

Comment: Shouldn't you check for `typeof`?

Comment: Hm, I don't know why they tell you to use `===`.

Comment: correction.  I was confused about the === comparison.  "In a language like Java or C, you can only switch on a few types. In JS, you can switch on anything. The value in the switch statement is compared with the value in each case using ===."

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL : It evaluates the condition faster than when you use the `==` operator. Because there's no type casting/conversion involved using  `===`Hence: `("1" === 1)`  returns false.

Comment: thanks everyone for the input, the code was completed using (typeof value) removing the var value = true and using {case "string":....and so on like mentioned by @Esailija

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `typeof` operator:

```
var value = true;
switch (typeof value) {
 case 'string':
```

Comment: you don't need `var value = true;`

Comment: The problem here is... what if it's an array, or even anything that's not a primitive? You'll still get 'object'...

Answer (score 7):

```
function detectType(value) {
  switch (typeof value){
    case 'string':
      return 'str';

    case 'number':
      return 'num';

    case 'object':
      return 'obj';

    default:
      return 'other';
  }
}
```

you could left out the `break;` in this case, because is optional after `return;`

Answer (score 3):

Read the question again - "write a function that uses switch statements on the *type* of the value".  You're missing anything about the type of the value, try using the `typeof` operator.

```javascript
typeof "foo" // => "string"
typeof 123 // => "number"
typeof {} // => "object"
```